# Python: How to add Firefox extensions in Selenium 4

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver, selenium4

The last version I used of Selenium was 3.141.0.

I am now transitioning to Selenium 4, and I am trying to figure out how to add extensions for Firefox, in Python 3.

Previously, something like this would work:

```
from selenium import webdriver

profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile(profile_path)
profile.add_extension('adblock_plus-3.10.2-an+fx.xpi')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(profile)
```

While attempting to make some adjustments that are apparently needed for Selenium 4, I tried the following code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

options = Options()
options.set_preference('profile', profile_path)
options.add_extension('adblock_plus-3.10.2-an+fx.xpi')

service = Service('/usr/local/bin/geckodriver')

driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options, service=service)
```

In Selenium 4.1.0, this gives `AttributeError`:

> ```
> options.add_extension('adblock_plus-3.10.2-an+fx.xpi')
> AttributeError: 'Options' object has no attribute 'add_extension'
> ```

Using `.add_extension()` with an `Options()` object is apparently not the correct way to add an extension. However, I am unable to find the right way.

It is potentially possible to create a `FirefoxProfile` and add the extension there, but at very least that seems to give a `DeprecationWarning`, and I don't know if it will work anyhow:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile(profile_path)
profile.add_extension('adblock_plus-3.10.2-an+fx.xpi')

options = Options()
options.set_preference('profile', profile_path)

service = Service('/usr/local/bin/geckodriver')

driver = webdriver.Firefox(profile, options=options, service=service)
```

> ```
> DeprecationWarning: profile has been deprecated, please pass in an Options object
>   driver = webdriver.Firefox(profile, options=options, service=service)
> ```

What is the proper way to add extensions in Selenium 4 for Firefox?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to add an extension directly on the Webdriver

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=service)
driver.install_addon('adblock_plus-3.10.2-an+fx.xpi')
```

https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_firefox/selenium.webdriver.firefox.webdriver.html#selenium.webdriver.firefox.webdriver.WebDriver.install_addon